# Error org/apache/http/conn/ssl/TrustAllStrategy on Karate test when using HTTPS

Tags: api, karate

I'm new to Karate and automation and asking for your advice on how to resolve my problem.
I'm running my Karate tests in HTTPS URL but I'm getting the error org/apache/http/conn/ssl/TrustAllStrategy
Anybody has encountered this error before? How did you resolve this?

This occurs after putting `* configure ssl = true` in my feature file

My karate-config.js looks like this:

```
function fn() {   
    var config = { 
        urlBase: 'https://<our url here>'
    }
    //karate.configure('ssl', true);    
    karate.configure('connectTimeout', 10000);
    karate.configure('readTimeout', 10000);  
    return config;
}
```

My feature file looks like this:

```
Feature: View Check History

Background:
* configure ssl = true
* url urlBase
```

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly have a library conflict, my guess is you have mixed Karate into an old project that already uses the Apache HTTP client. You have to resolve this yourself. My suggestion is try the quickstart here, which *will* work - and then you can compare with what's going on in your project: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Take the help of someone who knows Maven if needed. All the best.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24199704)

Comment: @MaartenDev thank you for your most valuable review comment, it is so heartening to see the hard work and the immense value that you add to stack-overflow. your feedback will be given the accordance that it deserves in future